# Is there option in cp command to reflect source path as destination path?

Tags: shell

If source and destination path are being same, how to skip re-typing it?
For example, I need to take a back-up of a file or rename it:

```
# taking back-up
$ cp ~/project/uboot/u-boot.img ~/project/uboot/ver1-u-boot.img

# renaming it
$ mv ~/project/uboot/u-boot.img ~/project/uboot/ver1-u-boot.img
```

Comment: Does: `(cd ~/project/uboot; cp u-boot.img ver1-u-boot.img)` count?

Comment: No without switching from the present working directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the curly braces!

```
$ cp ~/project/uboot/{,ver1-}u-boot.img
```

or to be more verbose

```
$ mv ~/project/uboot/{u-boot.img,ver1-u-boot.img}
```

The shell will reproduce what you have explicitly written in your question, which means you can write out the full path once. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)'s a good link for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
( cd ~/project/u-name-it; cp_or_mv file ver1-file )
```

or

```
base=base-path cp_or_mv $base/file $base/ver1-file
```

However this very much looks like a use case for a script or function to me.
As these can become quite sophisticated of course  (e.g. increasing the version would be nice)  I prefer to give a simple example more as an incentive ;)

```
# Untested, test well before using; should work in zsh & bash IFIAC
# usage:
#   bup directory [files...]
function bup
{
     local dir=$1
     shift
     for file; do
       cp $dir/$file $dir/ver1-$file
     done
}
```

HTH
Robert